# App browsing page bar

Tags: android, user-interface

Im developing an app and wanted to add some page browsing with those dots to identify your current page like the image below, can someone tell me how is that control called?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: If you are using viewpager, then check this - http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Android SDK that provides this "out of the box". It is probably implemented as a `LinearLayout` holding `ImageView` widgets, though there are plenty of ways of doing it. If your intention is to use this with a `ViewPager`, there is an implementation of this UI in [the ViewPagerIndicator library](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) and perhaps in other open source libraries as well.

If you really want to see what that app is doing, use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to inspect the running UI of that activity and see what widgets are involved.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default Android view for that.

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator